# InfluxDB Cloud : database not found

Tags: python, python-requests, influxdb, flux-influxdb

Using InfluxDB Cloud, integrated on the AWS suite. Just on the "setting up" page, token has been created, org and bucket. Writing to the bucket is OK, but retrieving data from it fails with a "database not found" error.

The example retrieving code

```
from flightsql import FlightSQLClient,connect
token = "xxxx"
org = "artilect"
url = "https://eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"
bucket="laser-filtre"

query = """SELECT *
FROM 'census'
WHERE time >= now() - interval '24 hours'
AND ('bees' IS NOT NULL OR 'ants' IS NOT NULL)"""

# Define the query client
query_client = FlightSQLClient(
  host = "eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com",
  token = token,
  metadata={"bucket-name": bucket})

# Execute the query
info = query_client.execute(query)
reader = query_client.do_get(info.endpoints[0].ticket)
```

Which is the tutorial's code with minimal modification. I get the error `FlightUnavailableError: Flight returned unavailable error, with message: empty address list:`   on the query_client.execute.

Trying with the http api

```
import requests

url = "https://eu-central-1-1.aws.cloud2.influxdata.com"
INFLUXDB_TOKEN= xxx

params = {"db" : "laser-filtre",
          "q" : """SELECT * FROM "courant" """}

headers = {
    'Authorization': f"Token {INFLUXDB_TOKEN}"
    }  

response = requests.get(url + "/query", params=params, headers=headers)
response.text
```

I get the error `'{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"error":"database not found: laser-filtre"}]}\n'`

Here is a screenshot of the InfluxDB, where we can see the bucket's name and measurements are okay.

[image]

Comment: I posted the question in the InfluxDB forum too : https://community.influxdata.com/t/database-not-found/30700/7
Somebody made it work by installing the package grpcio, but didn't work for me.
I think it was a problem with the trial version of InfluxDB Cloud, didn't try with the paying version though.